# What is $npm_package_config_entrypoint in IBM Cloud starters

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I can't run the the basic web starter kit generated from IBM Cloud.
It complains about "can't find module $npm_package_config_entrypoint

I have downloaded the generated code
Performed npm install

Trying to run by "start": "node $npm_package_config_entrypoint",

Comment: Any links to the instructions you followed?

Comment: @data_henrik

I was in my dashboard, created a new App, selected the most basic node.js runtime with express.js, added my cloud foundry service (MongoDb), generated the code, downloaded the code, run npm install in my IDE, tried to start the app via npm start.

I have publish the app on GitHub [link](http://github.com/HenrikGr/hgc-auth)